# Big Cartel - adding a note section before checkout

Tags: bigcartel

I have a big cartel website - Im trying to add a 'leave a note' section before payment but with absolutely no knowledge about html etc im finding it very difficult.
I know I have to go into custom mode and edit it but cant seem to find out what to input?
Any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there's not currently a way to include a "notes" section for your customer with Big Cartel, even with customization. Right now your only option is to use PayPal for checkout and take advantage of the Notes To Seller field they provide.